# Looking for simple Apache web control panel that allows me to match users to folders on a single domain

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, tomcat

I'm looking for a simple Apache control panel for a webserver that allows me to:

- Add user FTP accounts and match them to folders on a single domain web server
- Improvement: Mysql accounts managing
- Improvement: Tomcat support

No nameservers, no e-mail accounts managing (which can be disabled at least!).

Answer (score 1):

I hate this kind of software, but [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) does what you ask :-)

Edit : I didn't find any module in webmin for tomcat